# Quisiera saber que debo agregar para que los empleados se ordenen de forma que el empleado contratado recientemente aparezca primero

Tags: sql, pgadmin

```
select last_name,hire_date 
from hr.employees
where extract(Year from HIRE_DATE)=2007
```

Comment: `ORDER BY hire_date DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ordenar los empleados de forma que el más recientemente contratado aparezca primero, debes agregar la cláusula ORDER BY hiredate DESC a tu sentencia SELECT.

Esto garantizará que los empleados se ordenen de forma que el empleado con la fecha de contratación más reciente se muestre primero.

Tu sentencia SELECT completa se vería así:

```
SELECT lastname, hiredate FROM hr.employees WHERE extract(Year from HIREDATE)=2007 ORDER BY hire_date DESC
```